# Ambigious access on variadic template multi inheritence function call

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14, multiple-inheritance

So, I was working on an solution on how to solve the problem in [Looking for design pattern to reduce virtual method overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613155/looking-for-design-pattern-to-reduce-virtual-method-overloads)

My idea was too use variadic templates to describe which types may be accepted by a specific class. This might have a small use case, but I like to play around with templates...

Here is what I came up with (so far):

```
struct Struct
{
    virtual void doit() = 0;
};

struct StructA : Struct
{
    void doit() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

struct StructB : Struct
{
    void doit() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

struct StructC : Struct
{
    void doit() { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename Type>
struct Accepter
{
    void accept(const Type& t) { t.doit(); };
};

template <typename...Types>
struct MultiAccepter : Accepter<Types>... {};
```

When passing only a single type to `MultiAccepter` everything does as it should. 
The problems only occur as soon as I pass 2 or more template parameter types.
It looks like the compiler looses its ability to differ between distinct types.

```
int main()
{
    StructA struct_a;
    StructB struct_b;

    Accepter<StructA>                           accept_a;
    Accepter<StructB>                           accept_b;
    MultiAccepter<StructA>                      accept_multi_a;
    MultiAccepter<StructB>                      accept_multi_b;
    MultiAccepter<StructA, StructB>             accept_multi_ab;



    accept_a.accept(struct_a);              //OK
    accept_b.accept(struct_b);              //OK
    accept_multi_a.accept(struct_a);        //OK
    accept_multi_b.accept(struct_b);        //OK
    accept_multi_ab.accept(struct_a);       //NOK:
                                            //  error C2385: ambiguous access of 'accept'
                                            //      note : could be the 'accept' in base 'Accepter<StructA>'
                                            //      note : or could be the 'accept' in base 'Accepter<StructB>'
    accept_multi_ab.accept(struct_b);       //NOK:
                                            //  error C2385: ambiguous access of 'accept'
                                            //      note : could be the 'accept' in base 'Accepter<StructA>'
                                            //      note : or could be the 'accept' in base 'Accepter<StructB>'
                                            //  error C2664 : 'void Accepter<StructA>::accept(const Type &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'StructB' to 'const StructA &'
                                            //      with
                                            //      [
                                            //          Type = StructA
                                            //      ]
                                            //      note : Reason : cannot convert from 'StructB' to 'const StructA'
                                            //      note : No user - defined - conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile the code with `gcc 5.2` doesn't work either:
http://goo.gl/oVLHT8

I guess it's just a simple problem, but I just can't find a solution for it.
Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

---

**P.S.:** The example on this side describes a similar pattern: 
http://natsys-lab.blogspot.de/2013/07/c-variadic-templates-and-multiple.html

---

**Update:** It looks like the base class `Accepter<StructB>` defines a function `void accept(const StructA&)`. I still don't get why this is the case.

Comment: This is a dupe of...something. Without a using-declaration, names from different base class scopes don't overload.

Comment: @T.C. Right. It needs a variadic using directive, which I don't know how to do. Also note http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870498/using-declaration-in-variadic-template

Comment: @T.C. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28348429/2069064)? Even has the same comment from you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put togheter a solution using the pattern described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28349054/1149664

The trick is to inherit one base class `Accepter<T0>` at a time, and then push the remaining types further up the inheritance chain. I also made the methods const to get it consistent. You can tweak that as you like depending on what you need.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>


struct Struct
{
    virtual void doit() const = 0;
};

struct StructA : public Struct
{
    void doit() const { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

struct StructB : public Struct
{
    void doit() const { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

struct StructC : public Struct
{
    void doit() const { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename Type>
struct Accepter
{
    void accept(const Type& t) const { t.doit(); } ;
};

template <typename... Types>
struct MultiAccepter;

template <typename T0, typename...Types>
struct MultiAccepter<T0, Types...> : public Accepter<T0>, public MultiAccepter<Types...> {
    using Accepter<T0>::accept;
    using MultiAccepter<Types...>::accept;
};

template <typename T0>
struct MultiAccepter<T0> : public Accepter<T0> {
    using Accepter<T0>::accept;
};

int main()
{
    StructA struct_a;
    StructB struct_b;

    Accepter<StructA>                           accept_a;
    Accepter<StructB>                           accept_b;
    MultiAccepter<StructA>                      accept_multi_a;
    MultiAccepter<StructB>                      accept_multi_b;
    MultiAccepter<StructA, StructB>             accept_multi_ab;

    accept_a.accept(struct_a);              
    accept_b.accept(struct_b);             
    accept_multi_a.accept(struct_a);       
    accept_multi_b.accept(struct_b);     
    accept_multi_ab.accept(struct_a);    
    accept_multi_ab.accept(struct_b);     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works.